# Copy xml attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I would like to copy the attribute value from input to output.

Place of attribute in input is: katz-request/request/statebond-buy/payment/amount/@curr

Place of attribute in output is: katz-reply/reply/statebond-buy/amount/@curr

Here goes input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2" standalone="yes"?>
<katz-request>
   <request>
      <statebond-buy>
         <isin>PL0000108155</isin>
         <name>DOS0616</name>
         <count>2</count>
         <pay-date>2014-06-18</pay-date>
         <payment>
            <amount curr="PLN">200.00</amount>
         </payment>
      </statebond-buy>
   </request>
</katz-request>
```

Here goes my transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-2" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <katz-reply>
            <reply>
                <statebond-buy>
                    <count>
                        <xsl:value-of select="katz-request/request/statebond-buy/count"/>
                    </count>
                    <amount curr="DEM">
                        <xsl:value-of select="katz-request/request/statebond-buy/payment/amount"/>
                    </amount>
                    <tx-id>843084</tx-id>
                    <day-ref-id>837</day-ref-id>
                    <appl-id>000000000002267</appl-id>
                </statebond-buy>
            </reply>
        </katz-reply>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Here is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" standalone="yes"?>
<katz-reply>
  <reply>
    <statebond-buy>
      <count>2</count>
      <amount curr="DEM">200.00</amount>
      <tx-id>843084</tx-id>
      <day-ref-id>837</day-ref-id>
      <appl-id>000000000002267</appl-id>
    </statebond-buy>
  </reply>
</katz-reply>
```

that holds "DEM" instead of "PLN".

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of "Attribute Value Templates" here, and write out your XML like this

```
        <amount curr="{katz-request/request/statebond-buy/payment/amount/@curr}">
            <xsl:value-of select="katz-request/request/statebond-buy/payment/amount"/>
        </amount>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

But much better would be to re-write your XSLT to use the XSLT [Identity Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), and then it is just a case of copying across whole nodes.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-2" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="statebond-buy">
        <statebond-buy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="count" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="payment/amount" />
            <tx-id>843084</tx-id>
            <day-ref-id>837</day-ref-id>
            <appl-id>000000000002267</appl-id>
        </statebond-buy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both works great!

Second needs little bit more thinking to understand.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The identity transform is a common design pattern in XSLT so it is worth understanding. Effectively it means you only need to write templates for nodes you wish to transform. In your case you are only really transforming the **statebond-buy** element (because you need to add new child nodes to it).

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <katz-reply>
        <reply>
            <xsl:for-each select="katz-request/request/statebond-buy">
                <statebond-buy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="count | payment/amount"/>
                    <tx-id>843084</tx-id>
                    <day-ref-id>837</day-ref-id>
                    <appl-id>000000000002267</appl-id>
                </statebond-buy>
            </xsl:for-each>             
        </reply>
    </katz-reply>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works briliant and is rather simple.